# Does it make sense to add overlapping probabilities > 1?

Tags: probability, bells-inequality

I [read about a variation of Bell's inequality](http://www.johnboccio.com/research/quantum/notes/paper.pdf), expressed as
$$P_\text{same}(A, B) + P_\text{same}(A, C) + P_\text{same}(B, C) ≥ 1$$
It is later shown that the inequality is violated using QM.

Obviously, we see that some probabilities are overlapping because result is larger than 1. Does it make sense to add up overlapping probabilities?

Say, you draw cubes and balls, whether white or black, at random. So, you can add up $P(\text{black}) + P(\text{ball}) = 1$. But does it make sense? When you start testing it, the frequency of $P(\text{black or ball})$ will be $.75 < 1$, I guess. Will it prove anything?

Comment: You can add up whatever you want.  It's what you do with the result that matters.

Comment: A probability percentage cannot by definition be lower than 0% or higher than 100%.  If you're adding probabilities together, then by definition the result won't have any meaning.  Could you prove something useful if you assumed that triangles had 4 sides?  I wouldn't say so.